# Using Pandas and statsmodels for ordinary least squares

Tags: least-squares, python

Apologies in advance for the tedious beginner question.

I'm trying to translate a least-squares problem from a manual process (using Excel for matrix transposition and multiplication) to using the Python [statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/example_formulas.html#ols-regression-using-formulas) package. In this case, I'm performing an affine transform from a set of observed coordinates  to a set of ground coordinates in eastings (*E*) and northings (*N*). I've used the following formula to form the **A** (design) matrix:
$$
\begin{equation}
    f_i(a_{0}, a_{1}, a_{2}) = a_{0} + a_{1}x_{i} + a_{2}y_{i} \\
    f_i(b_{0}, b_{1}, b_{2}) = b_{0} + b_{1}x_{i} + b_{2}y_{i}
\end{equation}
$$
Which gives me a matrix that looks like:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & E_1 & N_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & E_n & N_n & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & E_1 & N_1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & E_n & N_n \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and a **b** vector, which is all *x* co-ordinates,  followed by all *y* co-ordinates:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_n \\ y_1 \\ y_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I also construct a square covariance matrix, **W**, using the square of the standard errors of the eastings and northings, arranged in a diagonal. This is used as the weight matrix during the least-squares process (the standard errors are assumed to be independent)

I then calculate:

$A^TWA$, $A^TWb$, and $(A^TWA)^{-1}$, then multiply $(A^TWA)^{-1}$ by $A^TWb$ to determine a vector **x**, which contains values for $a_0, a_1, a_2$ and $b_0, b_1, b_2$ 
5. Multiply **A** by **x**, and subtract **b** from the result, to determine a residuals vector, **v**.

I can calculate the unit variance ($\sigma0$) by obtaining the square root of $\frac{v^TWv}{observations - unknowns}$, and multiplying it by the *a priori* standard error of each co-ordinate, in order to assess the quality (*a posteriori* standard error) of the transform. I can also calculate the standard error of my **x** vector (the diagonal values of **Cx**) by multiplying $(A^TWA)^{-1}$ by $\sigma0^2$

Now that the tedious step-by-step manual explanation is out of the way, let's say I have Pandas DataFrames for **A**, **b** and **W**:

```
In [124]: A_matrix
Out[124]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 108 entries, 0 to 107
Data columns (total 6 columns):
As             108  non-null values
Eastings_a     108  non-null values
Northings_a    108  non-null values
Bs             108  non-null values
Eastings_b     108  non-null values
Northings_b    108  non-null values
dtypes: float64(4), int64(2)

In [125]: b_vector
Out[125]:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 108 entries, 0 to 107
Data columns (total 1 columns):
coordinates    108  non-null values
dtypes: float64(1)

In [162]: Weight_matrix
Out[162]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 108 entries, 0 to 107
Columns: 108 entries, 0 to 107
dtypes: float64(108)
```

How do I use `statsmodels.ols_regression` to easily calculate my residuals and $\sigma 0$?

Comment: I'm wondering why you don't use numpy (which is simpler to understand if you are not coming from an R background) http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html

Comment: @seanv507 That works, but I have to work out the residuals (Ax-b) manually.

Comment: Statsmodels performs all the matrix manipulations for you.  Once you fit the model, the [results instance](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLSResults.html) has all the information you are looking for.  For example, you can get the residuals by calling `.resid()`.

Comment: @urschrei... numpy returns residuals too? as an extra output parameter (unless i have misunderstood your whole setup)

Comment: @seanv I've put my progress so far on Github: https://github.com/urschrei/linalg. When I ran `np.linalg.lstsq`, using my design matrix and outcome vector, I got back parameters, but not residuals. It's quite likely I did something wrong, though.

Comment: @urschrei - my mistake - the output value "residuals" is actually the sum of residuals in numpy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculating σ0 is simple: take the square root of the returned `fit` object's `mse_resid` property.

Calculating the residuals: It's just the `resid` property of the returned `fit` object.